# how to create geometry object from data comes from database

Tags: jts-topology-suite

i have  lots of data From database  "MULTILINESTRING((5.5811647 50.6399323,5.5808065 50.6400428,5.5806085 50.640104))" "MULTILINESTRING((5.580576 50.6400012,5.5806085 50.640104,5.5806317 50.6401971,5.5806317 50.6402296,5.5806135 50.6404853))"  using it i want to create  MULTILINESTRING using it  how it possible uisng jts(java Topology suit )

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please take the [tour] to learn how to ask a good question. Coding questions are expected to show some effort/code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) to create a DataStore based on your database (since you don't say which one you are using I can't show an example). Then you can list the geometry for each of the features (the rows of the tables) and do whatever you intend to do with them.

Comment: i use postgresql  for storing data . i want to create map based on it using jts . can u help me to create geometry object from list of rows. Such geometry  object to used as draw polygon,point etc.....